# How to capture slicer value by DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to capture slicer value by DAX measure in all circumstances? Let's have sample data:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| category  | species | units |
+-----------+---------+-------+
| fruit     | apple   |     1 |
| fruit     | banana  |     1 |
| vegetable | carrot  |     1 |
| vegetable | potato  |     1 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

I added two measures:

Measure 1:

```
species selected = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[species])
```

Measure 2:

```
IsFiltered = ISFILTERED(Table1[species])
```

Case 1. All items in both slicers selected.
[image]

Case 2. (problematic case). **Fruits** selected and **Carrots** selected (it is possible when we untie slicers interactions). 
[image]

In case when we select **fruit** category from one slicer and **carrot** from another slicer there is a problem. This set of items is obviously empty. However definitely **carrot** from species have been selected and it is confirmed by IsFiltered measure which evaluates to True. Is there a way to capture that value in DAX measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both the `category` and `species` slicers come from columns on the same table, if you have both `fruit` and `carrot` selected, then the resulting table is empty and any measures (except ones that remove both filters) will therefore be working with blanks. You cannot have both filters apply simultaneously an expect them to act independently (even if the two slicer visuals don't cross-filter).

If you don't want your `species selected` measure to be influenced by `category`, the simplest thing to do would be to turn off filtering (under Format > Edit interactions) from the `category` slicer to the visual containing `species selected`.

This isn't always what you want though, so another possibility is to create a new table for the `species` slicer which has no filtering relationship from `Table1`. This will allow you to work with the slicers selections separately if that's something you need to do. (I've definitely had to do this before when I wanted a slicer to behave more like a parameter than a filter.)

---

**Edit:** To do what I suggested, create a new `Table2` in the query editor that references `Table1`, remove all columns other than `species` and remove duplicate if necessary. You should now have a single column table that is a list of unique species.

When you close and apply, Power BI will likely automatically create a relationship between the two tables, but you need to make sure it's exactly what you want. It needs to be a many to one relationship with a single filter direction.

[image: Table Relationship]

Once this is done, you'll need to replace the `Table1[species]` slicer with `Table2[species]` slicer as well as change references in measures where necessary.

Comment: So you suggest adding Table2 which would contain only species column. The species slicer would filter both tables. But after filtering Table1 would be empty, and Table2 would still contain carrot, because it would not have category column.

Comment: wouldn't there be any way to set up default species slicer value for fruit (say apple) and the other for vegetable (say carrot)?

Comment: I don't think that's possible yet. https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19055692-slicer-default-selected-values

Comment: What about pursuing the logic of building dynamic dax table for slave slicer (species) with row_no 1, 2, 3 ... and dynamically assigned labels such as apple for 1 and other list for the rest. If chosen Vegetables from the master slicer then for row_no 1 would dynamically assign carrots. The question is if it is possible to select 1 from slicer and display another value in that place.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what you're suggesting.